# Windows Vista File Explorer

Tags: windows-explorer

I have a computer with Windows Vista and I want to delete the Windows File Explorer search history and the history of files that have been opened.

There are instructions online to do this for Windows 7 to 10 but nothing for Windows Vista.

Does anyone know how to?

Comment: History of files opened is not retained. You need to set up a Group Policy File Auditing policy in advance to see what has been opened going forward.  Browsing history in File Explorer is part of Internet Browsing. In Vista, this can be cleared in Internet Options, General Tab and Delete - select what you want deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I use bleachbit for stuff like that. The history is located at %userprofile%\appdata\local\microsoft\windows\history